# Execution failed for task ':react-native-community_art:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-native-navigation

[Image error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EKLdY.png)I Building and installing the app on the device (cd android && ./gradlew installDebug).

> Task :react-native-community_art:compileDebugJavaWithJavac FAILED
> /Users/hadang/Documents/mobile-app/node_modules/@react-native-community/art/android/src/main/java/com/reactnativecommunity/art/ARTShapeShadowNode.java:25: error: cannot find symbol
> import static com.facebook.react.common.ArrayUtils.copyArray;
> ^
> symbol:   class ArrayUtils
> location: package com.facebook.react.common
> /Users/hadang/Documents/mobile-app/node_modules/@react-native-community/art/android/src/main/java/com/reactnativecommunity/art/ARTShapeShadowNode.java:25: error: static import only from classes and interfaces
> import static com.facebook.react.common.ArrayUtils.copyArray;
> ^
> Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
> Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
> 2 errors

- Node version: v20.3.0
- Java version:
- openjdk 17.0.9 2023-10-17 LTS
- OpenJDK Runtime Environment Zulu17.46+19-CA (build 17.0.9+8-LTS)
- OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM Zulu17.46+19-CA (build 17.0.9+8-LTS, mixed mode, sharing)
- React-native: 0.73.0
- React-native-navigation: 7.32.0

Have any solution for these bugs?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: ext {
        firebaseIidVersion = "21.1.0"
        buildToolsVersion = "34.0.0"
        minSdkVersion = 23
        compileSdkVersion = 34
        targetSdkVersion = 34
        ndkVersion = "25.1.8937393"
        kotlinVersion = "1.8.0"
        RNNKotlinVersion = kotlinVersion
    }

Answer (score 3):

just comment the import statement

> // import static com.facebook.react.common.ArrayUtils.copyArray;

in the file
node_modules/@react-native-community/art/android/src/main/java/com/reactnativecommunity/art/ARTShapeShadowNode.java